# Chomsky Hierarchy and Robot Framework

Tags: syntax, robotframework, turing-machines, pushdown-automaton, chomsky-hierarchy

I am writing a thesis about [Robot Framework](https://robotframework.org). I would like include a part about Chomsky Hierarchy, and describe in which hierarchy, does it belong to. As far as i can understand it, most programming languages can be described by CFG (Context Free Grammar) but are not part of it (eg. checking if variable was defined in C or multiple levels of parentheses). My question is if Robot Framework can be described in CFG -> can be checked with non-deterministic push down automat. I think it can by because of the table-like format of its syntax.